# Display XML (in formatted way) into a Razor Textarea

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a little problem.
I have a string (containing XML code).
Example:

```
<PosizioneRischio>
 <ParametriInput>
  <Utente>Utente</Utente>
<Input>
  <ClienteRichiesto>
    <CodiceCR>1</CodiceCR>
    <CodiceCRA />
  </ClienteRichiesto>
  <IstitutiRichiesti>
    <IstitutoRichiesto>1</IstitutoRichiesto>
  </IstitutiRichiesti>
  <DateContabiliRichieste>
    <DataContabileRichiesta>2014</DataContabileRichiesta>
    </DateContabiliRichieste>
 </Input>
 <ScalaImporti>5000</ScalaImporti>
</ParametriInput>
<PosizioneRischio>
```

I would like to show it in a textarea with razor, in a formatted way.

Supponing the string name is "xmlstring",
i would like doing something like:

```
@Html.TextArea("Info",xmlstring, new {cols="105", rows="30",@readonly="readonly",@disabled="disabled" })</td>
```

But in this manner, xml code appears flattened.. obvioulsy the result is not formatted. How can i make it formatted?
Sorry for the question..i'm a newbie

Comment: Can you include a sample of the generated Html?

Comment: <PosizioneRischio><ParametriInput><Utente>Utente</Utente><Input><ClienteRichiesto><CodiceCR>1</CodiceCR><CodiceCRA /></ClienteRichiesto><IstitutiRichiesti><IstitutoRichiesto>1</IstitutoRichiesto></IstitutiRichiesti><DateContabiliRichieste<DataContabileRichiesta>2014</DataContabileRichiesta></DateContabiliRichieste></Input><ScalaImporti>5000</ScalaImporti></ParametriInput></PosizioneRischio>

Comment: @user2328912 it's not html and it's not a valid xml. Root element has no closing tag

Comment: root element is <PosizioneRischio> and it has closing tag </PosizioneRischio>. When i put this string in sql editor, it is well formed, it is colorful and well indented

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var xml = "<root><A><B>0</B><C>0</C></A><D><E>0</E></D></root>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine (doc.ToString());
```

will print:

```
<root>
  <A>
    <B>0</B>
    <C>0</C>
  </A>
  <D>
    <E>0</E>
  </D>
</root>
```

So you need to do

```
@Html.TextArea("Info", XDocument.Parse(xmlstring).ToString(), new {cols="105", rows="30", @readonly="readonly", @disabled="disabled" })</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you were very useful! How can i make the XML tags coloured (in natural XML way, without using CSS tricks)? (For example internet explorer always give a color to tags automatically..)

Comment: Thanks. This helped me 8 years later.